# Getting the next 15 Events from Google Calendar (http requests)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to access a public Calendar using a node api and retrieve the 15 upcoming events in json format.

This is what I use at the moment:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myCalendarID/events?maxResults=15&key=MyKey
```

This gives me 15 events, but the events are the first 15 events from 2012 - I would like to get the upcoming 15 events from today. I tried using this:

```
&startMin=2014-08-09T10:57:00-08:00
```

But the result stayed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just figured out that you have to (!!) use both - timeMin & timeMax fields in order to get the next Events. I just tried to use the TimeMin parameter...